How to correctly approach successful load balancing in GridDB partition tables for data redistribution?
I was trying to implement load balancing for data redistribution in partition manually through my custom python script.
I have a partition p_table which has 4 partitions. I want to redistribute data from partition 3 to partition 0
from griddb_python import *
def redistribute_data():
    try:
        factory = StoreFactory.get_default()
        gridstore = factory.get_store(
            host='localhost',
            port= 31999,
            cluster_name='defaultCluster',
            username='admin,
            password='admin
        )
        col = gridstore.get_container("p_table")

        # Manually Moving data from partition 3 to partition 0
        rows_to_move = col.query("SELECT * FROM p_table WHERE partition_key = 3")
        for row in rows_to_move:
            new_partition_key = row[2] % 4  # Recalculating partition key
            row[2] = new_partition_key
            col.put(*row)

    except GSException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    finally:
        if gridstore:
            gridstore.close()
redistribute_data()


I am getting error as:
Error: Data inconsistency detected during partition key update
I want to know if there is some other approach or built-in feature for data redistribution in gridDB. Also please tell me why above method is not working as expected?
